# Why does computing one plotOutput block a completely independ second plotOutput in Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

I have an app with many plots that take a long time to render. In the future I want to have control in which order to render them but at the moment I want to familiarize with the logic when the plots are created and shown and there were some big questionmarks for me...

Consider the following easy app:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)

ui <- fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
    plotOutput("plot"),
    plotOutput("plot2"),
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    Sys.sleep(2)
    ggplot(iris) +
      geom_point(aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width))
  })
  output$plot2 <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(iris) +
      geom_point(aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server, options = list(launch.browser = TRUE))
```

One computation is fast, the other takes a lot of time.

However, when I start the app, both plots are invisible for about 2 seconds, not just the first one.

What is the reason behind that?

Answer (score 0):

Shiny will load everything in the server at one time so it waits for both functions, including the slow function, to finish before rendering the plots.

You could, however, simply wrap the `renderPlot` in `observeEvent` and wait for the input of an `actionButton` before running the slow function and plotting the code.

```r
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  sidebarPanel(
    actionButton("plotButton", "Plot 1"),
    actionButton("plot2Button", "Plot 2")
  ),
  mainPanel(
    plotOutput("plot"),
    plotOutput("plot2"),
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  observeEvent(input$plotButton, {
    output$plot <- renderPlot({
      ggplot(iris) +
        geom_point(aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width))
    })
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$plot2Button, {
    shiny::showNotification("Loading ...")
    output$plot2 <- renderPlot({
      Sys.sleep(2)
      ggplot(iris) +
        geom_point(aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width))
    })
  })
    
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: What does rendering mean? The process of computing an image out of the raw ggplot-Data? Or sending the image to the browser? Do you have any insight on how to flush the result out immediatly instead of waiting for all server-side functions to finish?

Comment: You can read this article about execution scheduling: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/execution-scheduling.html. I've noticed that the very first time the app is run there is an initialization and all the server-side code is run. Unless there is something explicitly telling shiny not to run a piece of the server code, like an if statement or an observe function, then it will run it. R is a single-threaded programing language.

Comment: Interestingly this website makes one think that values like computed plots are sent to the browser immediatly (if you look at the pictures)... But I found out yesterday that indeed shiny is waiting until all computations are ready. This is called flush cycle: see at the bottom of https://rstudio.github.io/promises/articles/shiny.html